# Encounter Error after installing Pytorch using pip in python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am using windows 10 OS with Python 3.5.
I am trying to run a program related to `torch`. So I installed `Pytorch` with the help of the instructions specified on their website: [Pytorch installation](https://pytorch.org/)

See the following image for selection of the downloadable:

[image: pytorch instalation]

I installed it using :

```
pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.4.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl 
pip install torchvision
```

I have encountered the following error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\twisted\trial\runner.py", line 701, in findByName
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\aims\Desktop\CNN\source\cnn4matrix.py", line 4, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\twisted\trial\runner.py", line 803, in loadByName
    return self.suiteFactory([self.findByName(name, recurse=recurse)])
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\twisted\trial\runner.py", line 704, in findByName
    return self.loadFile(_name, recurse=recurse)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\twisted\trial\runner.py", line 674, in loadFile
    module = SourceFileLoader(name, fileName).load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 385, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 806, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 268, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\aims\Desktop\CNN\source\cnn4matrix.py", line 4, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

After searching a lot I couldn't found anything related. Instead I found that I have tried: Reinstall with upgrade mode, the numpy library.

Please let me know what I can try.

**EDITED:**

This is the scenario for me:  I have install torch from the website instructions and then opened python terminal. just written `import torch` and the issue is what I got. Have a look at the image: https://ibb.co/fL53HT

Answer (score 0):

Please see this following thread:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/574

Basically, the problem might be that you have a folder called 'torch' in the same directory from where you are invoking python. So instead of the pytorch library being loaded, the folder named 'torch' is being picked up.

Do this: cd .. (to change directory), and then start python and import torch, it should work.

Comment: But this is not happening in my case. I have install torch from the website instructions and then opened python terminal. just written `import torch` and the issue is what I got.

Comment: Try reinstalling numpy. Have a look at this post: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4518 Download the numpy for python 3.5 and install it and try running pytorch.

Comment: I guess I have mentioned it already that I have reinstalled it.

Answer (score -1):

the one solution here if doesn't work after reinstalling Anaconda, then you can use `sth.` like Dependency Walker, open 
*`[Anaconda PATH]\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\_C.pyd`* 
 to detect what's wrong there.

and the other solution is caused by the directory torch which is generated in the same directory by compiling the source. try to simply changing the directory before open python.

Comment: I guess I have mentioned that I am using pip and anaconda I didn't used that word anywhere. Please let me know what solution do you prefer.